# AppCache html5, modifying the manifest file does not update the content of index.html?

Tags: html5-appcache

From this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp), it says :

> Once an application is cached, it remains cached until one of the
>   following happens:
>
> 1. The user clears the browser's cache
> 2. The manifest file is modified (see tip below)
> 3. The application cache is programmatically updated

Following the instruction from the internet, for the manifest file I use a version number. When I change the content of the index.html with 01.jpg to 02.jpg - I also changed the version number of the manifest file.

With the steps above, it works within my Win7 Wamp Server Local Host. But once I do the same steps in my web server (after uploading the file to the web server) - it doesn't work.

Can somebody please help me what did I do wrong ?

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://www.example.com/test/offline.appcache

Application Cache Checking event

Navigated to http://www.example.com/test/

Application Cache NoUpdate event
```

Above is from the Chrome browser console after I modified the version number of the manifest file (from #01 to #02) and the jpg file (from 01.jpg to 02.jpg) in the index.html file.

The offline.appcache CACHE file list no change, except the version number :

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2017-03-25 version#01
uploads/event.jpg
uploads/baby.jpg
/favicon.ico

NETWORK:
indexPHP.php
```

The index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="offline.appcache">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style></style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="uploads/01.jpg"> 
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onUpdateReady() {
alert("offline files will be updated");
  window.location.reload();
}
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', onUpdateReady);
if(window.applicationCache.status === window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
  onUpdateReady();}

</script>
```

the .htaccess file :

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

the "tree" :

```
example.com/.htaccess
example.com/favicon.ico
example.com/test/index.html
example.com/test/offline.appcache
example.com/test/uploads/01.jpg
example.com/test/uploads/02.jpg
```

Thank you in advanced.